# Control the style of svg

Tags: html, css

```css
.search-bar svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: red;
}

.search-button svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <form>
    <a class="search-button" type="submit">
      <svg class="svg-research" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
                     <rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"/>
                     <circle cx="116" cy="116" r="84" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
                     <line x1="175.4" y1="175.4" x2="224" y2="224" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
                  </svg>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to control the color of svg using CSS. I tried using different classes and ids to do this but none seem to have an effect on the color. I was able to change the size and position, but am failing to change the color. I wish to do this using a single ID or class instead of changing the color of the circle and line individually.

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <form>
    <a class="search-button" type="submit">
      <svg class="svg-research" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
                     <rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"/>
                     <circle cx="116" cy="116" r="84" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
                     <line x1="175.4" y1="175.4" x2="224" y2="224" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
                  </svg>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: SVG are not affected by 'color', that's for text. You need to use 'fill'

Answer (score 1):

Give the shared properties (e.g. `stroke` of line and `stroke` of circle) value of `currentColor`, and then you can control it via the `color` property of the `svg` (or any common ancestor they inherit from):

```css
.search-button svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: red;
}
 .search-button svg line,.search-button svg circle{
   stroke: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <form>
    <a class="search-button" type="submit">
      <svg class="svg-research" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
        <circle cx="116" cy="116" r="84" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
        <line x1="175.4" y1="175.4" x2="224" y2="224" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="8"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is what's done under the hood in Font Awesome and other
libraries. It can be done too for `height` and `width`, if you give them value in `em` units, you can control it later with `font-size` which is inherited too.